# sum of powers regarding stochastic kernel

Tags: operator-theory, power-series, density-function

I am having difficulty to prove some of the proof of Theorem 5.7.1. from the book, "Chaos, Fractals, and Noise" by A. Lasota. I think it is a simple problem, but somehow am not able to verify it. I hope to get some help.

Part of the proof that I am having difficulty to understand is as follows:

**Problem:** Let's assume the following inequality holds:
\begin{equation}
\int_G V(x) Pf(x) dx \leq \alpha \int_0^\infty V(x) f(x) dx + \beta,\, 0\leq \alpha <1,\, \beta \geq 0.
\end{equation}

Also, let
\begin{align}
E_n(V|f) := \int_G V(x) P^n f(x) dx
\end{align}
where $\{P^n\}$ is a sequence of Markov operator. For your reference, $P$ is a linear operator. Using the above inequality,
\begin{align}
E_n(V|f) \leq \alpha E_{n-1} (V|f) + \beta
\end{align}
By induction, the following holds:
\begin{align}
E_n(V|f) \leq \frac{\beta}{1-\alpha} + \alpha^n E_0(V|f).
\end{align}
What I don't understand is how the constant part $\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$ is derived. I tried the followings.

**My try**:
\begin{align}
E_n(V|f) &\leq \alpha E_{n-1}(V|f) + \beta\\
&\leq \alpha (\alpha E_{n-2}(V|f) + \beta) + \beta\\
&\leq \alpha (\alpha (\alpha E_{n-3}(V|f) + \beta) + \beta) + \beta\\
&\vdots\\
&\leq \alpha^n E_0(V|f) + \alpha^{n-1} \beta + \alpha^{n-2} \beta + \ldots + \alpha \beta + \beta
\end{align}
By sum of geometric series,
\begin{align}
\alpha^{n-1} + \alpha^{n-2} + \ldots + \alpha + 1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha^k = \frac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}
\end{align}
Hence, it becomes
\begin{align}
E_n(V|f) &\leq \alpha^n E_0(V|f) + \beta \frac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}\\
&\leq \alpha^n E_0(V|f) + \beta \frac{1}{1-\alpha}.
\end{align}
I am not sure if it is the right derivation.

I greatly appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: Your derivation is correct. I believe the author uses $\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$ instead of $\beta\frac{1-\alpha^n}{1-\alpha}$ simply because it is simpler than the latter and the former doesn’t depend on $n$. It is also possible that the form $\frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$ will be used in the proof later. If you are not sure of these kind of things, you can always use induction to verify.